# What happens to questions on the Apple Support Communities website when you delete an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

What happens to the questions and answers on the official Apple Support Communities website when you delete their associated Apple ID?

Are these deleted, remain as-is, have their username anonymized, or something else?

Comment: did you check your self ?

Comment: The Apple ID has not yet been deleted.